# PHP curl getting 404 while in browser all is fine

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_DF.htm - I have this url, in the browser it works fine, but If I make a request using this:

```
$url = 'http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_DF.htm';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
exit;
```

I get this result:

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_DF.htm [content_type] => text/html; charset=windows-1251 [http_code] => 404 [header_size] => 214 [request_size] => 72 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 14.925294 [namelookup_time] => 5.401249 [connect_time] => 5.643545 [pretransfer_time] => 5.643608 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 87314 [speed_download] => 5850 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 12.941717 [redirect_time] => 0 )
```

the http_code is 404, why this happens?

**UPDATED:**

```
$url = 'http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_DF.htm';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.rlsnet.ru');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
exit;
```

still getting 404

Comment: Hmm, if you do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);`, what do you get in your `$data`?

Comment: Probably because the site doesn’t like to be accessed by bots, and has implemented counter-measures against it. (The easiest one of those is to expect a user-agent header that sounds like a common browser, so it is also the easiest one to defeat by adding one of those.)

Comment: after adding CURLOPT_HEADER, I still getting 404

Comment: Is your browser and cURL on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with your code.

Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0)` it could be a problem of timeout based on the connection time you posted from `print_r`

What's your curl version? mine is 7.22.0

Answer (score 0):

Same code gives me `[http_code] => 200`

Maybe there's a problem in your curl installation.

Try to check your `phpinfo()`

cURL support    enabled

cURL Information    7.30.0

Age 3

Features

AsynchDNS   No

Debug   No

GSS-Negotiate   No

IDN Yes

IPv6    Yes

Largefile   Yes

NTLM    Yes

SPNEGO  No

SSL Yes

SSPI    No

krb4    No

libz    Yes

CharConv    No

Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp

Host    x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2

SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1e

ZLib Version    1.2.8

Comment: which config should i change in php?

Comment: Adding my configuration to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to set User-Agent and Referer:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.rlsnet.ru');
```