# PHP CURL works on windows, but getting a 404 on Linux

Tags: php

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_1.htm');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
exit;
```

I use this code on my windows machine and the page is loaded well with code 200 ok, but if I put this code on my hosting linux, then I get 404 error, what can be the reason of that?

Comment: er.. just to be on the safe side, is cURL installed in linux?

Comment: yes if it were not installed, it won't be even executed, the execution is ok, but the answer is 404

Comment: Did you check the URL is the same when you tested your code on linux?

Comment: I just executed the exact same code on c9.io, which worked. It seems to me that the code is correct.

Comment: Why are you spamming the SO with same questions? First [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089349/php-curl-getting-404-while-in-browser-all-is-fine), then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094142/php-different-response-headers-404-and-200) and again this question.

Comment: you've executed it in linux or in windows?

Comment: no there are no answers to THIS question

Comment: I think your hosting cannot give permission to execute cUrl because of PHP safemod etc.

Comment: the function itself is executed, IT WORKS FINE, but the answer is 404

Comment: Perhaps your hosts/network/dns configuration is screwed. Install lynx and try the url with it. But don't post the same question more than once..

Comment: can you tell me which configs may affect to this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its easier to use **file_get_contents** if you only need the content of the page.

Sometimes curl is not enabled or its a bug in the curl module.

```
<?php
$res = file_get_contents('http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_1.htm');
echo $res;
```

Comment: the same happens with file_get_contents I get 404 error

Comment: Then its possible that the port is blocked for outgoing connections. Is it a hoster? Or your own server?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: no, look if the url is http://www.rlsnet.ru - it will be okay, but this url http://www.rlsnet.ru/tn_alf_letter_1.htm - gives me an 404 error and only in linux, in windows is all okay